# Need to do a Map<K,Map<V,List<Y>>>

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects of a class that have a `LocalDate` attribute
I need to make a Map that has the key being the year and the value another map that the key is the month and the value the list of that object
Like this:

```
Map<Integer, Map<Month, List<K>>>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Loop your list and put it in the map

Comment: Got plenty of ideas.  You won't be interested in them, since they have nothing to do with whatever you're asking about, since I can't tell what that is.

Comment: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.getDate().getYear(), Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.getDate().getMonth())))`

Comment: shmosel, its work! Thank